# Performance improvement strategies for VM / interpreter?

Tags: c++, c, performance, interpreter, vm-implementation

I have written a simple VM in C, using a simple switch of instructions, without any instruction decoding whatsoever, but performance is terrible.

For simple aritmetic operations the VM is about 4000 times slower than native C code for the same operations. I tested with a group of arrays of length 10 million, the first consisting of the program instructions, random + - * / operations, 2 arrays holding random integers and the third array being the operation target storage.

I was expecting to see 3-4 times drop in arithmetic performance, so that `4000x really blew me away. Even the slowest interpreted languages seem to offer higher performance. So where I am going wrong with my approach and how can I improve performance without resorting to JIT compilation to machine code?

The implementation is... basically the simplest I could come up with:

```
begin:
    {
        switch (*(op+(c++)))
        {
        case 0:
            add(in1+c, in2+c, out+c); goto begin;

        case 1:
            sub(in1+c, in2+c, out+c); goto begin;

        case 2:
            mul(in1+c, in2+c, out+c); goto begin;

        case 3:
            div(in1+c, in2+c, out+c); goto begin;

        case 4:
            cout << "end of program" << endl;
            goto end;

        default:
            cout << "ERROR!!!" << endl;

        }
    }

end:
```

UPDATE:
I was toying with the length of the program when I noticed the QElapsedTimer I was using to profile was actually broken. Now I am using the clock() function from  and according to it the computed goto is actually running on par with the native code, maybe a tad lower. Is that result legit??? Here is the full source (it is ugly I know, it's just for testing after all):

```
#include <QtGlobal>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

#define LENGTH 70000000

void add(int & a, int & b, int & r) {r = a * b;}
void sub(int & a, int & b, int & r) {r = a - b;}
void mul(int & a, int & b, int & r) {r = a * b;}
void div(int & a, int & b, int & r) {r = a / b;}

int main()
{
    char * op = new char[LENGTH];
    int * in1 = new int[LENGTH];
    int * in2 = new int[LENGTH];
    int * out = new int[LENGTH];

    for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; ++i)
    {
        *(op+i) = i % 4;
        *(in1+i) = qrand();
        *(in2+i) = qrand()+1;
    }

    *(op+LENGTH-1) = 4; // end of program


    long long  sClock, fClock;


    unsigned int c = 0;
    sClock = clock();

    cout << "Program begins" << endl;

    static void* table[] = {
        &&do_add,
        &&do_sub,
        &&do_mul,
        &&do_div,
        &&do_end,
        &&do_err,
        &&do_fin};

#define jump() goto *table[op[c++]]

    jump();
do_add:
    add(in1[c], in2[c], out[c]); jump();
do_sub:
    sub(in1[c], in2[c], out[c]); jump();
do_mul:
    mul(in1[c], in2[c], out[c]); jump();
do_div:
    div(in1[c], in2[c], out[c]); jump();
do_end:
    cout << "end of program" << endl; goto *table[6];
do_err:
    cout << "ERROR!!!" << endl; goto *table[6];
do_fin:

    fClock = clock();
    cout << fClock - sClock << endl;

    delete [] op;
    delete [] in1;
    delete [] in2;
    delete [] out;

    in1 = new int[LENGTH];
    in2 = new int[LENGTH];
    out = new int[LENGTH];

    for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; ++i)
    {
        *(in1+i) = qrand();
        *(in2+i) = qrand()+1;
    }

    cout << "Native begins" << endl;

    sClock = clock();

    for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i += 4)
    {

        *(out+i) = *(in1+i) + *(in2+i);
        *(out+i+1) = *(in1+i+1) - *(in2+i+1);
        *(out+i+2) = *(in1+i+2) * *(in2+i+2);
        *(out+i+3) = *(in1+i+3) / *(in2+i+3);
    }

    fClock = clock();
    cout << fClock - sClock << endl;

    delete [] in1;
    delete [] in2;
    delete [] out;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to remove that `Sleep(1)` you've put in your code for debugging. ;) Seriously though, are you by any chance calling any system functions during each iteration?

Comment: @avakar - absolutely nothing is being called, the whole program loop consists of only a switch statement that calls appropriate functions and increments the instruction pointer. The debug builds is even slower, about 9000x performance drop. It is still pretty fast thou, those 10 million operations take a tiny fraction of the time it takes to dynamically allocate that memory, but still I'd prefer to have higher performance, it does seems to be possible.

Comment: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/07/12/computed-goto-for-efficient-dispatch-tables/

Comment: Have you considered telling us a bit more about your VM? How can I improve the performance of my code, which you know next to nothing about, is kind of hard to answer.

Comment: The approach sounds reasonable, so the problem probably lies in the details you left out.

Comment: Added the so called "implementation" - didn't add it the first time because there is really nothing to it. @BoBTFish - will try to implement computed goto when I have the time to see if it helps.

Comment: Do you have the code on github or somewhere so that we could look at it?

Comment: @avakar - I added the loop to the question ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Darek Mihocka has a good and in-depth writeup on creating fast interpreters in portable C: http://www.emulators.com/docs/nx25_nostradamus.htm