# Huge interpreter performance delta between Core2 and i7

Tags: performance, cpu, interpreter

I am implementing an interpreter, and after some meddling I finally managed to get decent performance - on my work PC - a core 2 processor, the interpreter performance was only about 7% lower than the same native code, which is pretty good for me.

Then I got home I ran the benchmark there, and the difference between interpreted and native code has risen to about 60-70%.

My question is why is that big difference? Is the core 2 processor perhaps suffering from a memory bottleneck, starving native code and "equalizing" performance closer to the interpreted code? Or is the i7 processor more efficient in processing or something? Maybe there is some way to utilize extra features and maximize interpreter performance and bring it closer to the native performance of the i7?

The test is based on the code here: [Performance improvement strategies for VM / interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720357/performance-improvement-strategies-for-vm-interpreter?rq=1)

work PC - core 2 duo @ 3GHz, 4 GB of DDR2 ram, windows 7, GCC

home PC - ivy bridge i7 @ 4GHz, 16 GB of DDR3 ram, windows 7, GCC

compiled with -O3 optimization, even thou different levels of optimization made little to no difference

Also, I made sure benchmark fits into the memory to avoid using the HDD.

Comment: I doubt this can be properly answered with zero code.

Comment: Please clarify the following:

PC at Work: processor, ram, HDD cache.
PC at home: processor, ram, HDD cache.
Also please provide your code.

Comment: @Crackers done, also linked the topic with the test code

Comment: What options did you use to compile?

Comment: What is the workload that you're using to benchmark? Being within 7% of native is likely not possible for any kind of CPU bound load for an interpreter.

Comment: @Novikov - it was just integer arithmetic - not really an "interpreter" in the full context of it, just some profiling for one, source is in the linked topic

Comment: And when you say its within 7% of native code, do you mean the interpreted arithmetic is within 7% of the native code required to run the same arithmetic or are you saying the interpreter is within 7% of the same interpreter written in native code?

Comment: @Crackers - I mean on the core2 machine the interpreted task takes only 7% more than the same task, written in C and compiled to native machine code. On i7 that gap grows to about 70%.